# I need to display the data, if at least one string present in another column using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in a table, column 1 contains `tom jerry` and column 2 has `tom xxxx` . I need to fetch the row at least one string is present the other column data

```
column1         column2 
-----------------------------
tom jerry   :   tom xxx
tiger       :   tom yyy
tiger lion  :   lipard
lion tom    :   tiger lion 
23          :   235 452
23          :   23
```

Expected result:

```
column1          column2 
---------------------------
tom jerry   :    tom xxx 
lion tom    :    tiger lion 
23           :   23
```

Comment: (1) SQL is not best suited for this sort of processing.  (2) What database are you using?  (3) Is there a maximum of two parts in each string?

Comment: i am using my sql database

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use instring function to achieve this. Function depends on the database you use. Below is the query,

```
select * from table1 where col1 > col2;



select distinct t1.* from table1 t1
inner join table1 t2
on (instr(substring(t1.col1, instr(t1.col1, ' ') -1), col2) > 0);
```

Comment: i am using my sql data base can you guide on that

Comment: If its mySql, same query will help you

Comment: @shibu: can you provide more commentary than merely "not working"? What happens when you run it?

Comment: actually while am running the query i am getting the empty response and sometimes am getting no such substring found

Comment: Please use this query, select * from table1 where col1 > col2;  Provided the same in the answer

Comment: thanks for the update,if this query will work out in db2?

Comment: this is query is fetching only the same value present in the columns .expectations need to display any of one string is present in anther column

Answer (score 0):

You'd be able to achieve this by creating a function wherein you will pass value of column1 and column2. The function will do the heavy-lifting of checking if column1 value (multiple words separated by whitespace) has any of its word matching in column2 value. The pseudo code of function should be something like this -

```
Function bool IsCol1WordPresentInCol2(varchar2 col1value, varchar2 col2value)
```

Step 1: Split col1value based on whitespace to get series of words

Step 2: Split col2value based on whitespace to get series of words

Step 3: Outer loop to iterate through all words of col1 (extracted from step 1)

Step 4: Inner loop to iterate through all words of col2 (extracted from step 2)

Step 5: Check if the col1 and col2 words do match. At any point, if any match is found, return true from the function; else false.

Step 6: Based on the returned bool value from this function, you'd be able to identify, in your calling logic, if that record satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

1. Put both columns to another table with identity column (to identify each row)
2. Write a function to split text by a string (in this case pass a space)
   Here you can use built in function if it is higher than SQL Server 2016
3. Get the identity and the splitted data to 2 tables each for column 1 and 2
4. Join the 2 tables for matches in Col-Split data, and get the IDs
5. Now Query for the data in table in above 1

Here is the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5878c7b1d0012d3979990d5ff9cfeb9d) assuming that the code is for **SQL Server 2016**

Comment: with out creating another table ,i need to fetch the column values is it possible

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use a regular expression for the data you have presented:

```
where column1 regexp replace(column2, ' ', '|') or
      column2 regexp replace(column1, ' ', '|')
```

This may or may not work as stated.  For instance, this will match "lion" and "lions" -- that meets what you are describing as I read it.  That said, you can modify the patterns to enforce word breaks if you have something slightly different in mind.